# How to set a notification in Android before a specified date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

I'm making an application where the user can set reminders for friends' birthdays, but I'm stuck with storing the date type in the database and also with setting a notification, as I said in the title, before the specified date.

How can I do that?

This is my code, where I'm just showing on the text button the date the user chose, but I want to store that date and set a notification 2-3 weeks before that specific date.

This is my code:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;

        // set selected date in button
        addBirthdayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1)
        .append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear)
        .append("-"));
    }
}
```

And the database code (I have tried something in the database, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing there). So I would appreciate any help here:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "_database";

private static final String BIRTHDAY_TABLE_NAME = "birthday_table";
public static final String BIRTHDAY_ID = "birthday_id";
public static final String BIRTHDAY_NAME = "birthday_name";
public static final String BIRTHDAY_LAST_NAME = "birthday_last_name";
public static final String BIRTHDAY_GENDER = "birthday_gender";
public static final String BIRTHDAY_AGE = "birthday_age";
public static final String BIRTHDAY_DATE = "birthday_date";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + BIRTHDAY_TABLE_NAME + " ( "
        + BIRTHDAY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + BIRTHDAY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + BIRTHDAY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + BIRTHDAY_GENDER + " TEXT,"
        + BIRTHDAY_DATE + " DATETIME,"
        + BIRTHDAY_AGE + " INTEGER );";

SQLiteDatabase database;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BIRTHDAY_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

public void setBirthdayData(String birthdayName, String birthdayLastName, String birthdayGender
,int age) {
    database = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(BIRTHDAY_NAME, birthdayName);
    cv.put(BIRTHDAY_LAST_NAME, birthdayLastName);
    cv.put(BIRTHDAY_GENDER, birthdayGender);
    cv.put(BIRTHDAY_AGE, age);
    cv.put(BIRTHDAY_DATE, getDateTime());
    database.insert(BIRTHDAY_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: how about using [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Okay, but how in what type of data i would store date? I mean how to store it from activity where i'm selecting date in database?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this concern, I don't think it is necessary to store it in the database. Just store it in an variable, set an Alarm Manager for any moment you want and if you don't need the notification anymore you can delete it.

If you still want to store date time in the database, I would suggest store them as Integer. This is an example how I store time-stamp in my app:

> ```
> private static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE = "create table "
>         + Constants.NOTES_TABLE
>         + "("
>         + Constants.COL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
>         + Constants.COL_TITLE + " text not null, "
>         + Constants.COL_CONTENT + " text, "
>         + Constants.COL_TYPE + " text not null, "
>         + Constants.COL_CATID + " integer not null, "
>         + Constants.COL_CREATED_TIME + " integer not null, "
>         + Constants.COL_MODIFIED_TIME + " integer not null "
>         + ")";
> ```